# Daily automatic update of stock quotes via REST API and Cronjob. Or is there a more sophisticated way?

Tags: api, json, wp-remote-get

I'm building a stock database with WordPress. There is a custom Post Type `stocks` with the fields `last_price` and `ytd_return` (ACF). The database will hold around 2000 stocks.

For the stock quotes I plan to use alphavantage (https://www.alphavantage.co) which offers a REST API to pull updated quotes.

As I only want end-of-day data I plan the following: Every night run a "CronJob" inside Wordpress which pulls the updated stock quotes for all the stocks and calculates YTD performance.

Now the question:
What is the most straightforward way to do this?
Is it wise to loop through all my posts (stocks) and use `wp_remote_get()` to update the data?
I expect to get problems with php execution times...

Or is there a better way to accomplish my goal with another php solution?
For example I thought about setting up an own table in the sql db and insert the new data there.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. So you fetch data from a remote source and according to that need to update 2 custom fields for ~2000 posts? If you run a proper cron (be it `php /.../../wp-cron.php` or via WP CLI), execution time won't be a problem, as the process may take as long as it needs

Comment: OK, thank you. Maybe that really isn't a problem then.... :)
Maybe my idea works and I thought too much about it. let's try....

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if the WordPress/PHP method is too slow, you could directly construct an SQL query. If none of that really works: do it in batches: Have it start at 2am, and update X posts every 5 minute (have one cron that runs daily at night, this then starts  several "sub"-crons)

Comment: I will try that. Do you maybe have a small example code for such an cron +  subcron job?

Comment: I gave an [answer that outlined](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300902/how-to-use-wp-ajax-in-wp-cron/300907#300907) this, but no real code there, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to separate your data from wp-data. To realize your idea, setup a new data table for time series data. Write a php script to request your data from desired source and create a cronjob. If your hoster does not provide cronjob creation, use a cronjob service. Depending on the amount of data you request, you probably have to create approx. 10 cronjobs.

Then, create a new table for YTD performance values and create a new php script to calculate YTD performance. This should work very quickly, so you will probably need only one cronjob (I suppose, maximum 4 cronjobs).

Now you will have the time series data and the performance data in two separate tables. To show YTD data in your WordPress, create a `shortcode` in your `functions.php` like I did [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296266/how-to-implement-content-from-external-database-into-wordpress-text-page).